# Any way to remove whitespace from dropdown menus in Windows 8.1/2012 R2?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, context-menu, whitespace, windows-server-2012

I've recently transitioned from Windows 7 to a Windows 8.1 environment. In doing so, I've noticed a lot of little UI changes that I didn't anticipate. Most have actually ended up being helpful.

One that has irked me since the change is the whitespace between menu items on dropdown menus. See the picture for an example:

[image: Whitespace Menu]

On Windows 7, this same application had the options stacked directly on each other without the whitespace in between. I'm guessing this is some sort of touchscreen assistance feature, but I can't figure out how to disable it.

Any help is appreciated.